# how to put item from database into style in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

i have an array from database like this

```
aa (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]

0: {id_button: 1, id_sound: 1, nama: "wik", nama_sound: "wik.wav"}
1: {id_button: 2, id_sound: 2, nama: "ihh", nama_sound: "ihh.wav"}
2: {id_button: 3, id_sound: 3, nama: "ayy", nama_sound: "ayy.wav"}

length: 3__proto__: Array(0)
```

i want to put them into style ,i've tried this but it doesnt work

```
 stylebutton = {this.state.pattern == item.id_button ? styles.item.nama+Big : styles.item.nama }
```

i expected it becomes

```
stylebutton = {this.state.pattern == 1 ? styles.wikBig : styles.wik }
```

is there any other way to put them in ?

Comment: Try: `styles[item.nama + 'Big']`.

Comment: Thanks you man , I've struggling with this for 2 hours